Che fine ha fatto la domanda sulla resilienza?
Qualche ora fa era presente una domanda sulla diffusione recente, in vari contesti diversi da quelli originari, del termine “resilienza”. Perché è stata cancellata? Era interessante.

Non riesco a vederla.

@egreg: È qui: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/8373/a-cosa-%c3%a8-dovuta-la-popolarit%c3%a0-del-termine-resilienza.

Anche secondo me è peccato che sia stata cancellata.

Riaperta. Anch'io la trovo interessante; il termine è di moda e abusato.

Adesso ricordo che le domande sul Meta dovrebbero essere tradotte in inglese.

@Gio: I think that no one has given any answer because it's no so easy to find an answer immediately. But the question is interesting and deserves to remain at the site.
